# Angular CDK Drag Drop on touch screen

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have a project with multiple cards that I want to move.
However, when users touch two of them at the same time and try to move them in different directions the movement is always to one of those directions.
I am using Drag and Drop (https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag)

Any suggestions on how to fix that?
Thank you!